# Optima of a multivariable function having set some of the variable fixed

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization

Assuming we have a multivariable function f(x,y,z). Is there a name for the optima of this function at f(x,y, z=c) with respect to x and y? (c is a constant)

Comment: For fixed $c$, why not just let $g(x,y)=f(x,y,c)$, and then optimize $g$?

Comment: True, but I was wondering whether there is a name for it, such as partial optima...